# How to pass dynamically menu content in partial page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

Layout.cshtml

```
 <table style="width:100%;" class="backcss">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 20%;  " valign="top" class="corner">
                @Html.Partial("_Menu")                
            </td>
            <td valign="top" align="center">
                @RenderBody()
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

_Menu.cshtml (partial page)

```
 @if (ViewData["MenuITem"] != null)
 {

    foreach (var item in ViewData["MenuITem"] as IEnumerable<Conference_Project.Areas.Master.Models.MenuItem>)
    {        
        <b> @item.controller</b>
       <b>@item.action</b>       
   }
}
```

MenuItem.cs( class)

```
public class MenuItem
 {
    public MenuItem(string area, string controller, string action, string name)
    {
        this.area = area;
        this.controller = controller;
        this.action = action;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public string area { get; set; }
    public string controller { get; set; }
    public string action { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

controller

```
public ActionResult _Menu()
    {
        List<MenuItem> obj = new List<MenuItem>();
        obj.Add(new MenuItem("Master", "User", "ViewProfile", "Profile"));
        obj.Add(new MenuItem("Master", "User", "StepI", "Abstract"));           
        ViewData["MenuITem"] = obj;
        return PartialView();
    }
```

I wanted to pass LeftMenu content using controller  for that I tried like passing through partial page view in controller but not working

1) how to pass dynamically menu content in partial page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Html.Partial("_Menu")` just renders the html from your partial into the layout. If you want to call a server method that generates the menu items, then you need to use `@Html.Action()` (or `@{ Html.RenderAction(); }`)

```
<td style="width: 20%;  " valign="top" class="corner">
    @Html.Action("_Menu", "YourControllerName")                
</td>
```

I would however recommend that you pass the model to the `_Menu.cshtml` view rather that using `ViewData`

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult _Menu()
{
    List<MenuItem> menu = new List<MenuItem>();
    menu.Add(new MenuItem("Master", "User", "ViewProfile", "Profile"));
    .... // add more items
    return PartialView(menu);
}
```

and in `_Menu.cshtml`

```
@model IEnumerable<Conference_Project.Areas.Master.Models.MenuItem>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{        
    <b>@item.controller</b>
    <b>@item.action</b>       
}
```

Comment: first one work  fine. Please could you tell me how to do it in my second  case?  second part I ask later sorry for that

Comment: I gave you an answer to your question :)  If you have a new question, then you need to ask a new question. And its not clear what you asking anyway (the code does not make any sense)

Comment: actually  I wanted to active tab for two different action

Comment: @Pravin, I see you have deleted the 2nd bit. My best guess was that your trying to add a specific class name (`class="active"`) to the `<li>` element based on certain conditions? When you ask your new question, make sure to explain clearly what your trying to achieve :)

Answer (score -1):

What ever you want to pass right into other controler/view should be returned in previous action, I mean:

```
public ActionResult _Menu()
    {
        List<MenuItem> obj = new List<MenuItem>();
        obj.Add(new MenuItem("Master", "User", "ViewProfile", "Profile"));
        obj.Add(new MenuItem("Master", "User", "StepI", "Abstract"));           
        ViewData["MenuITem"] = obj;
        return PartialView(RETRUNVALUE);
    }
```

As RETURNVALUE put values you will use in controller of partial view

Comment: @Stephen Muecke solution work for me . please  put solution for second part